# Object equality behaves different in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have these statements and their' results are near them.

```
string a = "abc";
string b = "abc";

Console.Writeline(a == b); //true

object x = a;
object y = b;

Console.Writeline(x == y); // true

string c = new string(new char[] {'a','b','c'});
string d = new string(new char[] {'a','b','c'});

Console.Writeline(c == d); // true

object k = c;
object m = d;

Console.Writeline(k.Equals(m)) //true

Console.Writeline(k == m); // false
```

Why the last equality gives me false ?

The question is why ( x == y ) is true ( k == m ) is false

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between == operator and Equals() method in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529422/difference-between-operator-and-equals-method-in-c)

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Actually I am not asking the difference between Equals and ==

Comment: Following this post: [When should I use == and when should I use Equals?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/29/when-should-i-use-and-when-should-i-use-equals.aspx) k == m is false because the compiler can only call the non-overloaded version of == as it doesn't know that the contents of c and d are both string references. As they are references to different strings, the identity operator returns false.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string a = "abc"; 
string b = "abc"; 

Console.Writeline(a == b); //true
```

String references are the same for the same string due to *String Interning*

```
object x = a; 
object y = b; 

Console.Writeline(x == y); // true
```

Because the references are the same, two objects created from the same reference are also the same.

```
string c = new string(new char[] {'a','b','c'}); 
string d = new string(new char[] {'a','b','c'});
```

Here you create two NEW arrays of characters, these references are different.

```
Console.Writeline(c == d); // true
```

Strings have overloaded == to compare by value.

```
object k = c; 
object m = d;
```

Since the previous references are different, these objects are different.

```
Console.Writeline(k.Equals(m)) //true
```

`.Equals` uses the overloaded String `equals` method, which again compare by value

```
Console.Writeline(k == m); // false
```

Here we check to see if the two references are the same... they are not

The key is figuring out when an equality is comparing references or values.

Objects, unless otherwise overloaded, compare references.

Structs, unless otherwise overloaded, compare values.

Answer (score 10):

In the case of strings, the `==` operator is overloaded to test for value equality, when using `object` reference equality is used.

Since `c` and `d` *are* strings, when you use `Equals` in the `k` and `m`, the overloaded method is used.

And `c == d` is `true` for the reason state above - value equality is used on `string` types as the operator is overloaded.

Comment: @Nick - As you posted, string interning is responsible :)

Comment: Actually the problem is if (k == m) is false why (x == y) is true ?

Comment: @Ryu - If that's what you wanted to ask, why didn't you?

Comment: If I didnt, I havent mentioned the " Console.Writeline(x == y); // true " part.

Comment: @Ryu - You posted it is `true`, but didn't ask about it.

Comment: @Oded, string interning applies to `string` literals. The strings `c` and `d` do not use interned strings because they're not created from literals.

Answer (score 3):

Because they are two different object references. The built-in comparison for this is to compare whether they point to the same actual object or not.

Due to *String Interning*, `a` and `b` are both references to the same string object.

`c==d` is true because the string equality operator is being used.

Comment: Following your answer, explain why `c == d`?

Answer (score 2):

```
   string c = new string(new char[] {'a','b','c'});
   string d = new string(new char[] {'a','b','c'});

   Console.WriteLine(c == d); // true

   object k = c;
   object m = d;

   Console.WriteLine(k.Equals(m)); //true

   Console.WriteLine(k == m); // false
```

Generates IL code, like this:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.3    
IL_0002:  newarr      System.Char
IL_0007:  dup         
IL_0008:  ldtoken     <PrivateImplementationDetails>{61BB33F4-0CA5-4733-B259-764124AD1A79}.$$method0x6000002-1
IL_000D:  call        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.InitializeArray
IL_0012:  newobj      System.String..ctor
IL_0017:  stloc.0     
IL_0018:  ldc.i4.3    
IL_0019:  newarr      System.Char
IL_001E:  dup         
IL_001F:  ldtoken     <PrivateImplementationDetails>{61BB33F4-0CA5-4733-B259-764124AD1A79}.$$method0x6000002-2
IL_0024:  call        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.InitializeArray
IL_0029:  newobj      System.String..ctor
IL_002E:  stloc.1     
IL_002F:  ldloc.0     
IL_0030:  ldloc.1     
IL_0031:  call        System.String.op_Equality   //STRING EQUALITY 
IL_0036:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_003B:  nop         
IL_003C:  ldloc.0     
IL_003D:  stloc.2     
IL_003E:  ldloc.1     
IL_003F:  stloc.3     
IL_0040:  ldloc.2     
IL_0041:  ldloc.3     
IL_0042:  callvirt    System.Object.Equals
IL_0047:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_004C:  nop         
IL_004D:  ldloc.2     
IL_004E:  ldloc.3     
IL_004F:  ceq         //CEQ INSTRUCTION: **VALUES** EQUALITY !
IL_0051:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

As you can see the last instruction call [CEQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ceq.aspx) instruction that makes comparison of values equality pushed on stack. The values pushed on stack are *references* of both boxed string, which are *not* equal.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `string1 == string2`, the comparison uses the `string` type's overloaded `==` operator, which compares the strings' values.

When you say `object1 == object2`, even though they're strings in this case, they won't qualify as strings for the purposes of finding an operator. So the comparison uses the default `==` operator, which compares the *references* for equality.  Which means, if the two objects aren't the exact same object, it will return false.

Answer (score 1):

As seen on [C# FAQ on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/29/when-should-i-use-and-when-should-i-use-equals.aspx) - the compiler cannot use the overloaded method and falls back to comparing the references.

The bigger question is why it succeeds in the first object comparison. My best guess is that succeeds because a and b are both given the same reference. For c and d, you are forcing different references.

Answer (score 1):

`String` has overloaded the equality operator so that you can use `==` for value comparison.  Hence

`a == b //true`.

When you're downcasting them to object, you're only comparing references. 
`String` looks into an internal [string-pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx) if another string instance is already available,  otherwise a new instance will be created and added to the pool. So actually `a`, `b`, `x` and `y` are even the same reference, that's why

`x == y //true`.

With using the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9.aspx) of `String`, you're forcing .NET to create a new instance even if another string with the same value(length and character sequence) exists. That's why

`k == m //false`

http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_String_Theory%E2%80%94String_intern_pool

Answer (score 1):

Building on Bob2Chiv's, I tried the equivalent in VB (VS2010):

```
    Dim a As String = "abc"
    Dim b As String = "abc"

    Console.WriteLine(a = b) ' True

    Dim x As Object = a
    Dim y As Object = b

    Console.WriteLine(x = y) ' True

    Dim c As String = New String(New Char() {"a"c, "b"c, "c"c})
    Dim d As String = New String(New Char() {"a"c, "b"c, "c"c})

    Console.WriteLine(c = d) ' True

    Dim k As Object = c
    Dim m As Object = d

    Console.WriteLine(k.Equals(m)) ' True

    Console.WriteLine(k = m) ' True (Yes, True!!)

    Console.WriteLine(k Is m) ' False (Like in C#)

    Console.WriteLine(a Is b) ' True (Like in C#)
```

(At least I think it's the equivalent - I welcome being corrected on this.)

Moral?: Be careful of `==` in C# - prefer `.Equals()` when the comparison of values is what's desired?

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator compares references (the memory addresses) while .Equals compares the actual object values. In the case of string, you get lucky and two identical strings can refer to the same address frequently. One of the joys of managed languages.